# Artemis HA configuration for core bridges

Tags: activemq-artemis

We have 4 servers in two shared disk HA pairs, with core bridges between them. The core bridge configuration and the connectors they use (sms and sms1b) are identical on all 4 servers. The only differences being master vs slave ha, and the host names in the other fields (acceptor, artemis and node0 connector, name)

In testing we found the bridge works perfectly when the two lives are up, but sometimes when shutting down a live server, the backup never opens a consumer for the bridge.

Is this the intended way to configure a pair of HA servers with a core bridge, or is the backup server configured wrong?

```xml
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>ba-artms3.example.com</name>      
      <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
      <paging-directory>/data/ba_artemis/msg-sms1/paging</paging-directory>
      <bindings-directory>/data/ba_artemis/msg-sms1/bindings</bindings-directory>
      <journal-directory>/data/ba_artemis/msg-sms1/journal</journal-directory>
      <large-messages-directory>/data/ba_artemis/msg-sms1/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      <journal-buffer-timeout>132000</journal-buffer-timeout>
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <connectors>
            <connector name="artemis">tcp://ba-artms3.example.com:2539</connector>
            <connector name = "node0">tcp://ba-artms4.example.com:2539</connector>
            <connector name="sms1">(tcp://ba-artms3.example.com:61616,tcp://ba-artms4.example.com:61616)</connector>
            <connector name="sms1b">(tcp://ba-artms9.example.com:61616,tcp://ba-artms10.example.com:61616)</connector>
      </connectors>

      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
      <page-sync-timeout>620000</page-sync-timeout>

      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://ba-artms3.example.com:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;</acceptor>
         <acceptor name="cluster">tcp://ba-artms3.example.com:2539?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://ba-artms3.example.com:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>

      <cluster-user>msg-sms1-cluster</cluster-user>

      <cluster-password>redacted</cluster-password>
      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="msg-sms1">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>0</max-hops>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>node0</connector-ref>

            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>

      <ha-policy>
         <shared-store>
            <master>
               <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
            </master>
         </shared-store>
      </ha-policy>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>

         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <xi:include href="${configDir}/addresses.xml"/>

 <bridges>
     <bridge name="sms1_forwarder">
       <queue-name>UpdateOutboundForward_0</queue-name>
       <forwarding-address>UpdateOutbound</forwarding-address>
       <ha>true</ha>
       <failover-on-server-shutdown>true</failover-on-server-shutdown>
       <user>rave</user>
       <password>redacted</password>
       <static-connectors>
         <connector-ref>sms1</connector-ref>
       </static-connectors>
     </bridge>
     <bridge name="sms1b_forwarder">
       <queue-name>UpdateOutboundForward_1</queue-name>
       <forwarding-address>UpdateOutbound</forwarding-address>
       <ha>true</ha>
       <failover-on-server-shutdown>true</failover-on-server-shutdown>
       <user>rave</user>
       <password>redacted</password>
       <static-connectors>
         <connector-ref>sms1b</connector-ref>
       </static-connectors>
     </bridge>
  </bridges>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

Keep in mind that the `acceptor` on port `2539` is specifically used for clustering. There are 4 servers total: ba-artms3 (live), ba-artms4 (slave) & ba-artms9 (live), ba-artms10 (slave).

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce running 3 instances on my local system, which at least tells me that my failover configuration was correct, which is what I intended this question to be about. Thanks. In the mean time I'll work with the IT department to do further tests on the systems we saw the issue on.

Comment: I compiled all of my comments into an answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, I couldn't reproduce in my local, but when I went back to the QA environment, I found splitting the <connector> for sms1 and sms1b into one per server and listing each in the <static-connectors> fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was using one connector per server instead of the bracket and comma syntax:

```xml
<connectors>
  <connector name="artemis">tcp://ba-artms3.example.com:2539</connector>
  <connector name = "node0">tcp://ba-artms4.example.com:2539</connector>
  <connector name="sms1_1">tcp://ba-artms3.example.com:2539</connector>
  <connector name="sms1_2">tcp://ba-artms4.example.com:2539</connector>
  <connector name="sms1b_1">tcp://ba-artms9.example.com:2539</connector>
  <connector name="sms1b_2">tcp://ba-artms10.example.com:2539</connector>
</connectors>
```

And then listing both of them in the  list:

```xml
<bridge name="sms1b_forwarder">
  <queue-name>UpdateOutboundForward_1</queue-name>
  <forwarding-address>UpdateOutbound</forwarding-address>
  <ha>true</ha>
  <failover-on-server-shutdown>true</failover-on-server-shutdown>
  <user>rave</user>
  <password>redacted</password>
  <static-connectors>
    <connector-ref>sms1b_1</connector-ref>
    <connector-ref>sms1b_2</connector-ref>
  </static-connectors>
</bridge>
```

After that in the log instead of seeing:

```
2021-07-20 09:13:51,809 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224091: Bridge BridgeImpl@5886a172 [name=sms1b_forwarder, queue=QueueImpl[name=UpdateOutboundForward_1, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=13be52e3-cb0f-11eb-a851-000c29d5fa03], temp=false]@56414412 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=Bridge sms1b_forwarder) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=sms1b, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=ba-artms9-example-com], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is unable to connect to destination. Retrying
2021-07-20 09:13:51,880 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge BridgeImpl@983e222 [name=sms1_forwarder, queue=QueueImpl[name=UpdateOutboundForward_0, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=13be52e3-cb0f-11eb-a851-000c29d5fa03], temp=false]@7440d62 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=Bridge sms1_forwarder) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=sms1, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=ba-artms3-example-com], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
```

I was seeing:

```
2021-07-20 09:30:40,333 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge BridgeImpl@339a572d [name=sms1b_forwarder, queue=QueueImpl[name=UpdateOutboundForward_1, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=13be52e3-cb0f-11eb-a851-000c29d5fa03], temp=false]@3d5daf2e targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=Bridge sms1b_forwarder) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=sms1b_1, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=ba-artms9-example-com, TransportConfiguration(name=sms1b_2, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=ba-artms10-example-com], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
2021-07-20 09:30:42,206 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge BridgeImpl@47c22520 [name=sms1_forwarder, queue=QueueImpl[name=UpdateOutboundForward_0, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=13be52e3-cb0f-11eb-a851-000c29d5fa03], temp=false]@4905c3a8 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=Bridge sms1_forwarder) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=sms1_1, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=2539&host=ba-artms3-example-com, TransportConfiguration(name=sms1_2, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=2539&host=ba-artms4-example-com], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
```

Note both servers now showing up in the initialConnectors.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks essentially correct, but it's hard to tell with so many moving pieces - especially the extra `acceptor` for clustering. I've seen folks do that before, but it's not something I've ever tested or recommended so I'm not sure how it would function in practice. Theoretically it would be fine, but there are always complicating factors many of which are subtle.

It would be worth simplifying your configuration to only what's absolutely necessary to reproduce the problem. For example, configure just 1 bridge on 1 server connecting to a live/backup pair with all the brokers on your local machine on unique ports (i.e. no docker). Once you have that working you can keeping adding complexity and testing as you go to see where things break down (assuming they do).

Comment: It's worth nothing the cluster acceptor connection as it turned out to be important in mirroring. As recommended at the time (1) the 61616 connection isn't always up. It turns out with mirroring it's important that the forwarding happen on the always up cluster acceptor.
(1): https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.17.0/amqp-broker-connections.html

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean. Mirroring doesn't use clustering. It doesn't even use core connections (like clustering does). How is mirroring related to "the cluster acceptor connection" and what exactly is "the cluster acceptor connection"?

Comment: So if you implement DR mirroring as in the documentation then the acceptor on 61616 is not active on the replica (autoStart=false). What this has to do with core bridges is that the replica just like on the live cluster tries to establish a connection for the core bridges. If you do not use another always active acceptor then you will get errors in the log that it can't connect. I didn't have the mirror in the original question, but it's good to know for anyone who might be implementing the same.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the connection. The use-cases are completely different. In the configuration from your use-case you had a separate core `acceptor` for *clustering*. What you're talking about now is a separate AMQP `acceptor` for mirroring. Configuration for clustering and mirroring are completely different.